# Create KML in Ruby with ruby_kml and use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, kml, openlayers, ruby

I want to create a KML in Ruby and use it with Openlayers. But Openlayers only wants a real KML file. It's complicated to explain. Just look at my Code:

In my Controller I have the following method for the KML:

```
def kml

require 'ruby_kml'

kml = KMLFile.new
folder = KML::Folder.new(:name => 'Melbourne Stations')
[
    ["Berlin1", 52.520645, 13.409779],
    ["Berlin2", 52.520645, 13.409779],
    ["Berlin3", 13.409779, 52.520645],
].each do |name, lat, lng|
  folder.features << KML::Placemark.new(
      :name => name,
      :geometry => KML::Point.new(:coordinates => {:lat => lat, :lng => lng})
  )
end
kml.objects << folder
@kml = kml.render
return kml
end
```

And in my index View I will call the KML with the following Script:

```
<script>
loading.style.display="none";

var vector = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url:   '<%= @kml %>',
        format: new ol.format.KML({
            extractStyles: false
        })
    }),
    blur: parseInt(10, 10),
    radius: parseInt(3, 10)
});

var koordinate = 5.6;

var map = new ol.Map({

    layers: [vector],
    target: 'vector',
    controls: [] ,
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
        dragging: false,
        dragPan: false
    }),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([10.5 , 51.0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        minZoom: koordinate,
        maxZoom: koordinate,
        zoom: koordinate
    })
});

blur.addEventListener('input', function() {
    vector.setBlur(parseInt(blur.value, 10));
});

radius.addEventListener('input', function() {
    vector.setRadius(parseInt(radius.value, 10));
});
</script>
```

But this doesn't work because OpenLayers only handles a real KML. How can I solve this problem? Is there a possibility to do this with ruby_kml?

Comment: Hi @mark96.  Could you clarify how it's not working?  Perhaps include the error you're getting.

Comment: I don't get any error. The Problem ist, that Ruby KML creates the following lines: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1"> <Folder> <name>Melbourne Stations</name> <Placemark> <name>Berlin1</name> <Point> <coordinates>13.409779,52.520645</coordinates> </Point> </Placemark> <Placemark> <name>Berlin2</name> <Point> <coordinates>13.409779,52.520645</coordinates> </Point> </Placemark> <Placemark> <name>Berlin3</name> <Point> <coordinates>52.520645,13.409779</coordinates> </Point> </Placemark> </Folder> </kml>

But Openlayers can nothing do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using the KML inline, as opposed to an external source file, then rather than using the *url* option (which instructs the source to use a loader) you can just use the *features* option.  See http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html

Try something like

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.KML({
            extractStyles: false
        })).readFeatures('<%= @kml %>')
    }),
    blur: parseInt(10, 10),
    radius: parseInt(3, 10)
});
```

Comment: Hmm... I tried this, but I get the following Message: "Unresolved function or method readFeatures()"

Comment: Could you try pasting the rendered code, ideally into a http://jsfiddle.net.  You can generate the basics using the create jsfiddle button from http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/kml.html?q=kml

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure, if this is what you wanted but anyway. I typed the Code for the hole map into JSFiddle. Here is the Link: https://jsfiddle.net/3s7z04ha/ I changed the '<%= @kml %> to the data which is stored in the variable. I hope you can help :) If you need anything else, let me know!

Comment: Nearly, take a look at the changes I made here: https://jsfiddle.net/3s7z04ha/1/  (note the way you need to reproject your data).

Comment: Ok that worked. But is there a possibility that I can do this with my old map and my three overlapped div's? Because the reason I do this, is that later i want to reload the vector layer with a setTimeout function. And this only works with the 3 Layers... And I want my old map design back :D Can you help me there?

Comment: Ok I so here is my old Map an it worked great :)) https://jsfiddle.net/3s7z04ha/2/ But can you help me one more time? How to I refresh the vector layer every 5 seconds (because the data for the mL is in a database) without refresh the hole map. So the visitor should not see if there is something reloading?!

Comment: Great! Could you mark this one as complete and raise another question for the refreshing query. Its quite a different task to answer inside these comments :-)

Comment: Ok thanks for your help :) I will then raise another question later :)